# Move from SQL Server CE 4.0 + EF to SQLite

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, orm, xamarin.forms, sql-server-ce

I have a .NET WPF project which is using SQL Server CE 4.0 with Entity Framework.

I want to rework it into a Xamarin Forms project. I think the 'migration' of the backend will be almost seamless, except for the data access layer. I am confused as to what Xamarin supports. I can't use SQL Server CE with Xamarin forms, can I? What about SQLite? It is supported, as far as I can tell.

Ok, but then what about ORM? Right now I am making a heavy use of the EF navigation properties. Is there any way I could preserve this with SQLite?

How would you go about converting code which relies on EF and navigation properties, backed by SQL Server CE, to SQLite, while preserving the mentioned navigation properties?

Can I use Entity Framework with SQLite, on Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core supports SQLite, yes.

And SQL Compact is supported with EF Core, but only on Windows desktop.

Support for EF Core with Xamarin Forms is still in progress, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features

Comment: Let me see if I get this straight. My best bet on Xamarin Forms would be EF Core + SQLite, right? So, Xamarin Forms on .NET Standard, so I can use EF Core + SQLite. Am I getting this right? Thanks.